# Compare and return full path files in node overcoming Windows/Unix separator issues

Tags: node.js

I have code like this:

```
exports.fileRenamer = (config, file) => {
  switch (file) {
    case 'src/pages/PREFIX-load-error.js': return `src/pages/${config.vars.elPrefix}-load-error.js`
    case 'src/pages/PREFIX-not-found.js': return `src/pages/${config.vars.elPrefix}-not-found.js`
    case 'src/pages/PREFIX-landing.js': return `src/pages/${config.vars.elPrefix}-landing.js`
    case 'src/lib/base/elements/PREFIX-header.js': return `src/lib/base/elements/${config.vars.elPrefix}-header.js`
    case 'src/lib/base/elements/PREFIX-page-header.js': return `src/lib/base/elements/${config.vars.elPrefix}-page-header.js`
    case 'src/lib/base/elements/PREFIX-toggle-button.js': return `src/lib/base/elements/${config.vars.elPrefix}-toggle-button.js`
    default: return file
  }
}
```

It's obviously a callback that gets called to check if a file should be renamed -- if it does, it returns the renamed version.

This is working on Linux, but not on Windows.
I realise that the separator are different.
The obvious solution is:

- Use path-equal to compare the paths https://github.com/unional/path-equal
- Use path.join to stitch them together

However, this would make it 1) Impossible to use the neat case statement 2) Look horrible after the "return" part

Is there an easier way, so that I can retain the "neatness" of the existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep).

```
case `src${path.sep}pages${path.sep}PREFIX-load-error.js`: return `src${path.sep}pages${path.sep}${config.vars.elPrefix}-load-error.js`
```

Comment: Sweet. I was thinking of doing exactly that this morning. What about silly `C:\` prefixes Windows adds? Does fs.readdir return those ugly things too?